# pubnub.grant() read access not working in PUBNUB PAM

Tags: python-2.7, pubnub

I have implemented PAM at server side, for which I have tried to give access to individual client with different auth key. The Write access works as expected, but no client receives any message even if I grant them the read access. Here's how I've initialized my pubnub config;

```
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'sub-c-...'
pnconfig.publish_key = 'pub-c-...'
pnconfig.secret_key = "sec-c-..."
pnconfig.uuid = "server"
channel = "my_channel" 
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig) 

def my_publish_callback(envelope, status):
    #print 'status:', status.original_response
    pass 


class MySubscribeCallback(SubscribeCallback):
    def status(self, pubnub, status):
        if status.is_error():
            print("handle permissions here ERROR")
            if status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNAccessDeniedCategory:
                print("handle permissions here")

    def message(self, pubnub, message):
        global server_UUID
        d = message.message
        if type(d) == dict:
           if (d.get('server')): 
             pass 
           else:
               print 'dict>>',d
        else:
           print 'got>>', d 

pubnub.add_listener(MySubscribeCallback())
pubnub.subscribe().channels(channel).with_presence().execute() 

def input_take():
    while 1:
      data = raw_input("Send:") 
      if "yes" in data:
          grant(True, True, "robot")
      elif "no" in data:    
          grant(False, False, "robot") 

def send():
    c = 0
    while 1:
      print 'sending:', c  
      time.sleep(1.5)
      c += 1 
      pubnub.publish().channel(channel).message({pubnub.uuid:str(c)}).async(my_publish_callback)      

def grant(read, write, auth):           
        v=pubnub.grant()\
            .read(read)\
            .write(write)\
            .channels('my_channel')\
            .auth_keys(auth)\
            .ttl(60)\
            .sync()
        #print v.result
        for key, value in v.status.original_response.iteritems():
            print key ,":" , value
            pass

T = Thread(target=input_take) 
T.start()   
S = Thread(target=send)
S.start()
```

I am getting a status response of 200 while running the pubnub.grant() function.

```
status : 200
message : Success
payload : {u'auths': {u'robot': {u'r': 1, u'm': 0, u'w': 1}}, u'subscribe_key': u'sub-c-...', u'ttl': 60, u'channel': u'my_channel', u'level': u'user'}
service : Access Manager
```

but still no client is able to receive any message. I am using pubnub debug console for client testing and setting auth key same as in server "robot". Am I missing something ? Or do I need to configure something in PAM ? I am using PubNub version 4.0.12.

Comment: I've observed the behavior of read access. When granting read access to False actually unsubscribes the client from that specific channel. So if you want to grand the read permission again, the client need to subscribe again to that channel, in order to listen messages.

Comment: The reason why I was not viewing the received messages were because the client automatically gets unsubscribed. So when I subscribe again, I could read the messages successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comments above. I added a JavacScript code at client side, which tries to re-subscribe to that channel after every two seconds.

```
  function try_sub(){
    pubnub.subscribe({
        channels: ['my_channel'] 
    }, 

    function (status, response) {
        if (status.error) {
            console.log(status)
        } else {
            console.log("Subscribed Success w/ timetoken", response.timetoken)
        }
     }      

    );
    setTimeout('try_sub()',2000);
   }
```

Comment: Is that infinite or until it succeeds?

Comment: @CraigConover It was infinite before, but now i've added a check. If i get "forbidden" in subscribe callback function, then run this try_sub() function, else sit idle.